# Truncating with ascii symbols

Tags: php, split, truncate

i've a problem with the truncate php function..

```
<?php

print_r(truncate ('cia???☺☻♥♀♂☼•◘○♠♣xas?????!!!!----'));

function truncate($text) {
    $length = 100; 
    $ending = '...';
    $exact = true;
    $considerHtml = false; 
    $stripTags = false;
    $wordsLenght = 20;


    $textArray = explode ( " ", $text );

    foreach ( $textArray as $key => $word ) {
        if (strlen ( $word ) > $wordsLenght) {
            $truncatedWord = substr ( $word, 0, $wordsLenght );
            $textArray [$key] = $truncatedWord . "[...]";
        }
    }

    $text = implode ( " ", $textArray );
    // end truncate long word

    if (strlen ( $text ) <= $length) {
        return $text;
    } else {
        $truncate = substr ( $text, 0, $length - mb_strlen ( $ending, 'UTF-8' ) );
    }
}

// if the words shouldn't be cut in the middle...
if (! $exact) {
    // ...search the last occurance of a space...
    $spacepos = strrpos ( $truncate, ' ' );

    if (isset ( $spacepos )) {
        // ...and cut the text in this position
        $truncate = substr ( $truncate, 0, $spacepos );
    }
}

// add the defined ending to the text
$truncate .= $ending;

if ($considerHtml) {
    // close all unclosed html-tags
    foreach ( $open_tags as $tag ) {
        $truncate .= '';
    }
}

return $truncate;
```

The problem, whit the string o given, is that the truncate function doesn't work well with unicode symbols...

The result is this:

> cia???☺☻♥♀��[...]

Is there a way to split correctly?

I tried in different ways but none of them works correctly... I'm going out of mind :)

Comment: `substr` works on bytes, not characters: use `mb_substr` instead. you should know that utf-8 is a multibyte encoding.

Comment: The problem is still present, i get as a result "cia???☺☻♥♀��[...]" (the same i have before)

Comment: how did you change your code? show us.

Comment: inserting "mb_substr" ebery time "substr" is present..

Comment: You need to replace all of string functions by their multibyte equivalent: substr -> mb_substr, strrpos -> mb_strrpos, etc

Comment: i did, but it doesn't work...i put only real international letters.. there isn't the "[...]" at the end of the line like the previous example... https://3v4l.org/rtT1e